# How do I ensure copy & pasted slides from another PowerPoint Presentation are in the correct order when inserted using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm using this code to insert slides from another presentation easily. It works fine BUT I've noticed the copied slides come across in random order. i.e. not the same order they are in the PowerPoint file. How can I fix this please?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim PPDD As String
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long
Dim Z As Long

  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "PowerPoint Files", "*.pptx; *.ppt; *.pptm; *.ppsm", 1
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
        PPDD = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        End With


        X = InputBox("Please enter which position (slide number) you'd like the selected PowerPoint file to be inserted", "slide number", "1")
        Y = InputBox("Please enter the number of the first slide you want to copy", "slide number", "1")
        Z = InputBox("Please enter the number of the last slide you want to copy", "slide number", "1")

Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open(PPDD, WithWindow:=msoFalse)
For i = Y To Z
    objPresentation.Slides.Item(i).Copy
    Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Paste X
    Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Item(Presentations.Item(1).Slides.count).Design = _
        objPresentation.Slides.Item(i).Design
Next i
objPresentation.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was that it was entering them in reverse order. When you would call `Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Paste X`, it would *keep* pasting into that X position. What you really want is to progressively offset that original index as you paste.

I changed the variable handling but it is essentially the same.

```
Option Explicit 

Sub CopySlide()

    Dim pptStart As Presentation
    Set pptStart = ActivePresentation

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "PowerPoint Files", "*.pptx; *.ppt; *.pptm; *.ppsm", 1
        .Show

        On Error Resume Next
        Dim PPDD As String
        PPDD = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    If Len(PPDD) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "File not chosen. Closing."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim pptOpened As Presentation
    Set pptOpened = Presentations.Open(PPDD, WithWindow:=msoFalse)


    Dim indexInsertAt As Long
    indexInsertAt = InputBox("Please enter which position (slide number) you'd like the selected PowerPoint file to be inserted", "slide number", "1")

    Dim indexCopyFirst As Long
    indexCopyFirst = InputBox("Please enter the number of the first slide you want to copy", "slide number", "1")

    Dim indexCopyLast As Long
    indexCopyLast = InputBox("Please enter the number of the last slide you want to copy", "slide number", "1")


    Dim offset As Long

    Dim i As Long
    For i = indexCopyFirst To indexCopyLast

        pptOpened.Slides.Item(i).Copy
        pptStart.Slides.Paste (indexInsertAt + offset)

        pptStart.Slides.Item(indexInsertAt + offset).Design = _
            pptOpened.Slides.Item(i).Design

        offset = offset + 1
    Next i

    pptOpened.Close

End Sub
```